# Making first select <option> blank after mapping through array in JSX / React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, html-select

```
  render(){

    let { classes } = this.props;

    let list = classes.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <option >{item}</option>
      )
    })


    return(
      <div className="filter-bar">

        <form className="sort-form">
          <div className="classSelect">
            <span>select class</span>
              <select name="classSelect" onChange={this.handleClassChange}}>
                <option selected="selected"  >Please choose class</option>
                {list}
              </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

i want to map over an array and use each element as options in select dropdown, and also have an extra blank option which defaults until dropdown is clicked.

at the moment, the extra  i have is available in the list, but default is always first element from array, whereas i want the default to be "Please choose your class"

can somebody explain?

Comment: assign a `value` to the default option and use this value as initial state

Answer (score 5):

```
  render(){

const classes = [
  'Lorem',
  'Ipsum',
  'dolor',
  'Sit',
  'ames'
]

let list = classes.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <option >{item}</option>
  )
})


return(
  <div className="filter-bar">
    <form className="sort-form">
      <div className="classSelect">
        <span>select class</span>
          <select name="classSelect" onChange={this.handleClassChange.bind(this)} defaultValue="none">
            <option value="none" disabled hidden> 
            </option> 
            {list}
          </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
)
```

You can use a `disabled` and `hidden` `<option>` with value `"none"`. Instead of using the `selected` attribute, you should then use `defaultValue="none"` on the parent `<select>` to conform with modern react requirements.

Comment: This is causing problems with modern react since they are warning about using `selected` attribute now